# Compute the series of the measures

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $(X, A, m)$ be a probability space, and $E_n$ be measurable sets. Suppose that every $x$ belongs to exactly 3 of $E_n$'s, compute $\sum m(E_n)$.

I have not learned probability before, and my thought is to use integral instead of measure. $m(E_n)=\int 1_{E_n}$ but I don't know what the next step is. 
Can someone give a hint?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right idea, and then you want to use the monotone convergence theorem:

$$\sum m(E_n)=\int\sum1_{E_n}\,\mathrm dm.$$

If $x$ appears in exactly $3$ of the $E_n$, what is the value of $\sum1_{E_n}(x)$?

Comment: Is it the indicator function on the intersection of these three $E_n$?

Comment: No. We've fixed $x$, so don't think about intersections or unions. $1_{E_n}(x)=1$ if $x\in E_n$ and $0$ otherwise, so what does $\sum1_{E_n}(x)$ represent? What does it *count*?

Comment: The number of $E_n$ ?

Comment: Simplify a little. Let $n=4$, and $E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4\subset\mathbb R$. For *fixed* $x\in\mathbb R$, what does $\sum_{i=1}^41_{E_i}(x)$ mean? Cardinality should feel wrong; what does $x$ have to do with the cardinality of a set? Note that $0\le\sum_{i=1}^41_{E_i}(x)\le4$. Does that help?

Comment: Is it the number of sets of En in which x belongs to?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now I got it!